# Getting unexpected shape while slicing a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a 4D numpy array. While slicing for multiple indices in a single dimension, my axis get interchanged. Am I missing something trivial here.

```
import numpy as np
from smartprint import smartprint as prints

a = np.random.rand(50, 60, 70, 80)
b = a[:, :, :, [2,3,4]]
prints (b.shape)  # this works as expected 

c = a[1, :, :, [2,3,4]]
prints (c.shape)  # here, I see the axes are interchanged
```

Output:

```
b.shape : (50, 60, 70, 3)
c.shape : (3, 60, 70)
```

Comment: That's an often mentioned feature of array indexing, mixed advanced and basic indexing.  It's documented as well.  Use `a[1][ :, :, [2,3,4]]` if needed.

Comment: Thank you! that is really smart. I was reshaping it later  by swapping the axes. `c = np.swapaxes(c, 0, -1)`

Comment: The relevant docs section: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations that may help explain the problem.

Start with a 3d array, with the expect strides:

```
In [158]: x=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [159]: x.shape,x.strides
Out[159]: ((2, 3, 4), (48, 16, 4))
```

Advanced indexing on the last axis:

```
In [160]: y=x[:,:,[0,1,2,3]]    
In [161]: y.shape, y.strides
Out[161]: ((2, 3, 4), (12, 4, 24))
```

Notice that the strides are not in the normal C-contiguous order.  For a 2d array we'd describe this a F-contiguous.  It's an obscure indexing detail that usually doesn't matter.

Apparently when doing this indexing it first makes an array with the last, the indexed dimension, first:

```
In [162]: y.base.shape
Out[162]: (4, 2, 3)
In [163]: y.base.strides
Out[163]: (24, 12, 4)
```

`y` is this base with swapped axes, a `view` of its base.

The case with a slice in the middle is

```
In [164]: z=x[1,:,[0,1,2,3]]
In [165]: z.shape, z.strides
Out[165]: ((4, 3), (12, 4))

In [166]: z.base    # its own base, not a view
```

Transposing `z` to the expected (3,4) shape would switch the strides to (4,12), F-contiguous.

With the two step indexing, we get an array with the expect shape, but the F strides.  And its `base` looks a lot like `z`.

```
In [167]: w=x[1][:,[0,1,2,3]]

In [168]: w.shape, w.strides
Out[168]: ((3, 4), (4, 12))

In [169]: w.base.shape, w.base.strides
Out[169]: ((4, 3), (12, 4))
```

The docs justify the switch in axes by saying that there's an ambiguity when performing advanced indexing with a slice in the middle.  It's perhaps clearest when using a (2,1) and (4,) indices:

```
In [171]: w=x[[[0],[1]],:,[0,1,2,3]]

In [172]: w.shape, w.strides
Out[172]: ((2, 4, 3), (48, 12, 4))
```

The middle, size 3 dimension, is "tacked on last".  With `x[1,:,[0,1,2,3]]` that ambibuity argument isn't as good, but apparently it's using the same indexing method.  When this was raised in github issues, the claim was that reworking the indexing to correct this was too difficult.  Individual cases might be corrected, but a comprehensive change was too complicated.

This dimension switch seems to come up on SO a couple of times a year, an annoyance, but not a critical issue.

Comment: Thanks for the exact cases which make this clearer; more so for the historical perspective!