# Numpy indexing behavior with unexpected dimension ordering

Tags: python, numpy

```py
>> np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)[0,:,[2,3]].shape
(2,3)
>> np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)[0,[1,2],:].shape
(2,4)
```

I get the second one, but why the first one is not `(3,2)`?

In the first case, the first two indices (`0` and `:`) are basic indexing, and the last one (`[2,3]`) is advanced indexing.

According to the [guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing), deal with the basic indexing first (producing `(3,4)`-shaped view), then with advanced indexing it would get `(3,2)`-shaped copy. It looks like the single integer index (`0`) becomes advanced indexing, which makes no sense.

Comment: I had the exact same problem once, Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410804/3896008

Comment: @lifezbeautiful jesus the questions are identical, and I REALLY did searched for it but failed.

Comment: I get it for the `x[[[0],[1]],:,[0,1,2,3]]` case in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410804/3896008), because the first indice is advanced indexing; the `a[1, :, :, [2,3,4]]` case can be acceptable only if we consider the single int indice as advanced indexing. Anyway, thank @lifezbeautiful and @hpaulj for your help :)